# Knitr LaTeX Error: Command \C unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, miktex

I'm trying to knit a PDF document of a table with images, but I'm getting a LaTeX error and a pandoc error 43:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \C unavailable in encoding
>   T1.

The versions I'm working with:

- RStudio 1.0.143
- MiKTeX 2.96400
- Rmarkdown 1.6
- Knitr 1.17

LaTeX engine is pdflatex. Code:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(gdata)
library(knitr)
compound.data <- read.xls("CompoundInformation.xlsx")
compound.data$Structure2D <- sprintf("![](Images/%s.png)", compound.data$CID)
kable(compound.data)
```
````

Is there perhaps some special character in my R code I should be escaping?

Comment: I get similar error `! LaTeX Error: Command \U unavailable in encoding T1`. Did you find a solution?